# Moving a project from VS2015 to VS2017, TRACEDESGINTIME error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to move a C++ project from VS2015 to VS2017, while loading the project on vs2017, i get an error with

```
error : Designtime build failed for project 'C:\Coding_Projects\C++\Taxi\Taxi.vcxproj' configuration 'Debug|x64'. IntelliSense might be unavailable.

Set environment variable TRACEDESIGNTIME = true and restart Visual Studio to investigate.
```

Any help or information is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try following that instruction?

Comment: yes! i did. But unfortunately, i didn't find anything relevant to my work, some say need to update the VS2017. but it is already updated.

Comment: Did you try a rebuild ?

Comment: You may have to logout and login after changing the environment variable. Also make sure when you set it in the Windows GUI that you don't put the `=` in the value. [https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/)

Comment: Some project files contain paths local to each computer. If you have SDKs, external components in different places on each computer, you will have to configure these files.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I try to set environment variable "TRACEDESIGNTIME" to true and it didn't work. Even after restarting VS2017 and PC. 

However, i will look into project setup and will try to configure these files. 

thank you once again for all the help.

Comment: I suggest you try to repair visual studio and set error list to build only